# Automatically create modal form and switch to the specified tab (one liner)

Tags: delphi

I have a form (TFrmAbout) that has on it a TPageControl and some tabs.

I want to build a function (or procedure) that will create the form, set the active tab to the tab I send as parameter and then show the form.

```
procedure ShowAbout(Tab: TTabSheet);     
begin
  Result:= TfrmAbout.Create(NIL); // Action:= caFree;
  Result.Font:= MainForm.Font;
  Tab.TabVisible:= TRUE;  
  Result.PageCtrl.ActivePage:= Tab;
  Result.ShowModal;
end;
```

Use it like:

```
procedure ShowSystemTab;     
begin
  ShowAbout(TFrmAbout.tabSystem); //This won't work (of course)
end;
```

Question:
How do I pass the Tab parameter?

---

There are ugly solutions. For example, I could make ShowAbout a function that returns the form. But then I have to use an extra variable in "ShowSystemTab".

Comment: Pass its index, or name, or create an enumeration and pass such a value.

Comment: Index can easily change! So, absolutely no go. Name... sure, will definitively work, but.... meh.... I want to pass that actual tab object :)

Comment: My question is not "how do I make this piece of code work?" because there are some solution, but "how do I build it beautifully?" (maybe one liner). Or maybe something like Class-Reference Types

Comment: You can't pass a tab sheet because you it doesn't exist, it's created by your function. And Andreas has listed the other obvious possible solutions. How does the calling code decide which tab it wants to make active?

Comment: If so, I think your about box unit should contain an About Dialog API which can be used by other units. Don't let other units have access to the actual form class (`TfrmAbout`).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Yes... maybe there is no "elegant" solution. I agree. Maybe I ask too much :)

Comment: I mean you could pass an anon method whose job it was to select the active page. Or I could imagine lots more options. But again, how does the caller decide?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The "ShowAbout(tabXYZ)" is called from the main menu of the application.

Comment: @Gravity But how do you expect the main menu code to have access to a `tabXYZ` that hasn't been created yet? Chicken, meet egg.

Comment: Instead of `TTabSheet` instance your `ShowAbout` procedure could take callback of type `TInitActivePage = reference to function(About: TfrmAbout): TTabSheet;`. You invoke the callback after instantiating the form: `procedure ShowAbout(InitActivePage: TInitActivePage); begin ... Result.PageCtrl.ActivePage := InitActivePage(Result); ... end;` And finally `ShowSystemTab` becomes messy one-liner: `ShowAbout(function (About: TfrmAbout): TTabSheet begin Result := About.tabSystem; end);`. At that point you stop and think: was that really worth it? Delphi is not C#.

Comment: @PeterWolf - Yes. Not worth it indeed :) Well, it was just an exercise to see if there could be a trick to do this.

Comment: At this point the cleanest solution would be to use the tab name (NOT the index) as Andreas proposed. The name can change in time, but....

Comment: If you create an enum type with a value for each tab, then you can create a oneliner with the enum as parameter...